# Two different tenses or just one

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which of the following is the Correct English tense?
1. Had you have lunch?
2. Have you had lunch?
Are these both different English tenses or they mean the same?

Comment: 1 is wrong, 2 is not.

Comment: ‘Have you had lunch’ makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Had you have* is not grammatical: never, as far as I can think.

The auxiliary *have*, in any of its parts (*have*, *has*, *had*, *haven't*, *hasn't*, *hadn't*) can **only** be followed by the past participle (*had*, *seen*, *gone* etc), not by any other part of the main verb.

(There is a construction where *have* can be followed by an infinitive, eg *I had them build a house*, meaning "I caused them to build a house"; but this is a different construction. There must be an object (*them* in the example), and it does not behave as an auxiliary, eg *Did you have them build a house?*, not **Had you them build a house?*)

Comment: *Had you have come home, we would have had a party* is fine. Even *had you have **lunched** with us, we would have all been satisfied* would work, albeit in an unnatural way. But *had you have* ***lunch***, specifically, doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica: those aren't grammatical in my idiolect. But yes, they apparently are for some people.